# Can I run a script during the installation of a windows program?

Tags: java, windows, installation

I would like to run a small peice of program, perhaps a little scriptlet written in Java, during installation of a program on windows OS.

Is there a way this can be achieved, independent of which method has been implied of preparing the windows installer and which language has been used to make the program?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Refer to the user guide for your specific installer application that talks about running custom scripts.

Comment: That is sort of a step into the right direction for my issue, but I would like the integration process of the script to be independent of what installer application has been used. So in theory I am guessing, as long as a scriplet written in Java is provided, every installer app which allows for running of custom scripts should have its own method of integrating that script into the installation process. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you'd better provide an example of what you're talking about specifically, because I'm not sure I understand.  Yes, most installers allow you to run scripts.  Yes, they all do it a little differently.  But a script is a script; that script will do whatever you programmed it to do.

Comment: Thanks, that sums it up for me.